# Push notification actions not working on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am using firebase cloud messaging in my flutter app, am receiving notifications correctly in both IOS and android.

The problem is that I have made some actions to happen when notification is clicked as follow:

```
void configureFirebase() {
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');
    print(message['data']['nid']);
    print(message['data']['type']);
    firebaseIn(message['data']['nid'], message['data']['type']);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on resume $message');
    print(message['data']['nid']);
    print(message['data']['type']);
    firebaseOut(message['data']['nid'], message['data']['type']);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on launch $message');
    print(message['data']['nid']);
    print(message['data']['type']);
    firebaseOut(message['data']['nid'], message['data']['type']);

  },
);
}
```

This is working perfectly fine in android, but not in iOS. I am getting the notification i see it printed in the log but clicking on it do nothing. The firebaseout and firebasein functions are not called at all in iOS, since I have some `print`s in them!

Can someone help me and tell me why its not working only on iOS. I am really confused?